# Client instructions on Control Panel home?

Tags: ee2, control-panel

I'm trying to find an easy way to have basic instructions displayed when the client opens the CP (I'm using [NSM Publish Hints](http://ee-garage.com/nsm-publish-hints) for detailed instructions on entry windows).

I was using [DashEE](https://github.com/mrtopher/dashEE/issues/45), which was great, but since EE2.9, it hasn't been functioning properly so that I can't update anything.

How do you all provide basic on-screen instructions to the client so that when they open the Control Panel it's obvious how they should proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could inject JS using this [add-on](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js) into the area of the Control Panel you want the the help text to appear - then you can expand it to all relevant pages you want help on - not just the CP homepage.

JS...

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".contentMenu.create").before('<div class="helpText contentMenu"><p>Help Text goes here</p></div>');
});
```

Example CSS...

```
.contentMenu.helpText {
    background-color: honeydew;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 40px 30px;
    float: none;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Result...

[image: Control Panel Grab with Help Panel]

Obviously change your JS target for different pages in the Control Panel.

Comment: Lol upvote for honeydew.

Answer (score 0):

If these are static instructions (they generally won't be changing), you could craft an EE Accessory to just insert a new element on the CP Home Page with your instruction in them.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/accessories.html

Here's a pseudo-ish-code example:

```
function set_sections()
{
    // Check to see if you're on the CP Home Page
    // if not, return false

    // use the ee()->cp->add_to_foot() to add jQuery to insert stuff
    // kinda like this:
    ee()->cp->add_to_foot('
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#mainContent").prepend("<div class=\"contentMenu helptext\" style=\"width: 93.6%;margin-bottom: 1em;\"><div class=\"heading\"><h2>Help Text</h2><ul class=\"homeBlocks item\"><li>Help! I need to tell you all the helping things!</li></ul></div></div>");
        });
    ');
}
```

And tada!

[image]

**Edit** Welp, if it's something you need to change constantly, here is one option. Store a snippet with your instructions, and dump that instead of static stuff. Call your snippet `cp_help_text` or something. Snippet content:

```
<div class="contentMenu helptext" style="width: 93.6%;margin-bottom: 1em;">    
    <div class="heading">
        <h2>
            Help Text
        </h2>
        <ul class="homeBlocks item">
            <li>
                Help! I need to tell you all the helping things! Easily changed from the Design -> Template -> Snippets.
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And back to the accessory:

```
...
$snippet = ee()->db->select()
                   ->from('snippets')
                   ->where('snippet_name', 'cp_help_text')
                   ->get()->row_array();

ee()->cp->add_to_foot('
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mainContent").prepend("'.$snippet['snippet_contents'].'");
    });
');
....
```

Yup, seems convoluted! Perhaps someone can give you a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for this -- I'm actually looking for something that would be a bit easier to change (in other words, for not-necessarily static instructions), but I will try this out. I'm curious also how other people are dealing with this issue. What do you all do?

Comment: I edited my answer to slightly accommodate your question. Lol I know it's not the greatest answer but it would get it done. Hopefully someone else can chime in.

Comment: I decided to give your suggestion a spin; I was hesitant because I don't know anything about php. So I copied the first example of your code directly into a file (acc.cp_help_home.php), but when I try to implement it, I get an error saying "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in line 23" which is the 3rd to the last line, containing }); -- any idea what the problem would be? I would post the entire code I'm using, but not sure how to do that in a comment; do I need to edit the original post? I greatly appreciate your help with this!

Comment: Throw it in a pastebin and I will help you out! http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Oh and basically an easier method to my answer is contained in Peter Lewis' answer!

Comment: hi @jrothafer! I think I prefer the look of your solution to the other one (seems more integrated into the cp) so thanks so much for looking at this: http://pastebin.com/4dSULgMV

Comment: @edward oops! i accidentally put in a wrong quote. Here's the faulty line, with the quote fixed (it's the last one):            `$("#mainContent").prepend("<div class=\"contentMenu helptext\" style=\"width: 93.6%;margin-bottom: 1em;\"><div class=\"heading\"><h2>Help Text</h2><ul class=\"homeBlocks item\"><li>Help! I need to tell you all the helping things!</li></ul></div></div>");`

Comment: If you keep at it, and post pastbin updates, I'll be glad to keep helping you through the process.

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for your efforts. So I plugged in your revised code, but I'm still getting an error message, now it's: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting T_FUNCTION in line 37" Here's the updated version: http://pastebin.com/4dSULgMV

Comment: Yet another error! That same double-quote in my previous comment that I fixed, need to be escaped! so `"` need to be `\"`.

Comment: We may need to get down on a chat tomorrow or something, if you're still having problems. I have a many addons (Modules, Extensions, Plugins, and Accessories) in production in the wild. Let me get you an example Accessory I have living in production.

Comment: Here is a general working example for what you are trying to do: http://pastebin.com/hudj5KEy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29591/discussion-between-edward-and-jrothafer).